# Drive api not working inside service

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I made one activity and one service. Activity for just getting authorised once which is working fine but when i try to list files using same account in service it doesnt works.

Here is the **mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
private TextView mOutputText;
ProgressDialog mProgress;

static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY };

/**
 * Create the main activity.
 * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mOutputText = new TextView(this);
    mOutputText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    mOutputText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
    mOutputText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mOutputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    activityLayout.addView(mOutputText);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Calling Drive API ...");
    mOutputText.setText("hi");
    setContentView(activityLayout);

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName((null));
}


/**
 * Called whenever this activity is pushed to the foreground, such as after
 * a call to onCreate().
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        refreshResults();
    } else {
        mOutputText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
    }
}

/**
 * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
 * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
 * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
 *     activity result.
 * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
 *     activity result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                mOutputText.setText("Account unspecified.");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Attempt to get a set of data from the Drive API to display. If the
 * email address isn't known yet, then call chooseAccount() method so the
 * user can pick an account.
 */
private void refreshResults() {
    if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else {
        if (isDeviceOnline()) {
            new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
 * account.
 */
private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(
            mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

/**
 * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
 * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. Will
 * launch an error dialog for the user to update Google Play Services if
 * possible.
 * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
 *     date on this device; false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        return false;
    } else if (connectionStatusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
 * or out of date.
 * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
 *     Google Play Services on this device.
 */
void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
            connectionStatusCode,
            MainActivity.this,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * An asynchronous task that handles the Drive API call.
 * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
 */
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Drive API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call Drive API.
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of up to 10 file names and IDs.
     * @return List of Strings describing files, or an empty list if no files
     *         found.
     * @throws IOException
     */
        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // Get a list of up to 10 files.
            List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
            FileList result = mService.files().list()
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .execute();
            List<File> files = result.getItems();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                            file.getTitle(), file.getId()));
                }
            }
            return fileInfo;
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mOutputText.setText("");
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if(mCredential.getSelectedAccountName()!=null){
           sendBroadcast(new Intent("account").putExtra("account",mCredential.getSelectedAccountName()));
            finish();}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (mLastError != null) {
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
            } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                        + mLastError.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the required

**service code**

```
    void initialize(String id){
        account=id;
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                this, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(id);
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                .setApplicationName("Drive API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }
public void listRoot(final com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mService,  final listReturn listReturn) {
        final ArrayList<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        if (asyncTask != null && asyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
            asyncTask.cancel(true);
        asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
            Exception e=null;
            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... v){
                if(v!=null && v[0]==1 && e!=null)listReturn.throwError(e);
                else listReturn.list(files);
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    String pg = "";
                    for (; ; ) {
                        Drive.Files.List lst = mService
                                .files()
                                .list()
                                .setFields(mFolderFields)
                                .setMaxResults(100);

                        if (!pg.equals(""))
                            lst.setPageToken(pg);
                         FileList fl;
                        try {
                            fl = lst.execute();
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            fl=null;
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        if (fl.size() == 0)
                            break;
                        for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : fl.getItems()) {
                            if (files.contains(file))
                                continue;
                            else if (isRoot(file)) {
                                files.add(file);
                            }
                        }
                        if (pg.equals(fl.getNextPageToken()))
                            break;
                        pg = fl.getNextPageToken();
                        if (pg == null || pg.equals(""))
                            break;
                    }
                    publishProgress(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.e=e;
                    publishProgress(1);

                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Error comes in line

```
fl=lst.execute();
```

edit- Error log

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:284)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin.DriveUtil$2.doInBackground(DriveUtil.java:119)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin.DriveUtil$2.doInBackground(DriveUtil.java:97)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)

12-18 23:35:18.677 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
12-18 23:35:18.687 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
12-18 23:35:18.687 12181-12707/com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So you mean your code executing without any error, but your request is returning empty list. Right?

Comment: Code works fine in activity but not in service

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: i explained in the question.The line which gives error. lst.execute()

Comment: Can you specify the error?

Comment: logs just say this i am afraid com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin.DriveUtil$2.doInBackground(DriveUtil.java:110)
12-18 12:06:23.610 16372-16372/? W/System.err:     at com.amaze.filemanager.driveplugin.DriveUtil$2.doInBackground(DriveUtil.java:97)

Comment: and that line i told you is lst.execute()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98311/discussion-between-arpit-khurana-and-dhaval-patel).

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question - answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282761/google-drive-integration-using-current-activity/34380599#34380599), It is for GDAA, but the very same applies to the REST Api. See the bottom of the answer.

Comment: But i will have another problem here.This method passes activity object to that class.But my activity(client) is in a different package(apart from the activity i mentioned above which only is to be opened once for auth).So how will i pass activity object from a different package which is just interacting with the service

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a direct reaction to your email referring to the [RESTDemo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) Github project. Quoting:

> i checked out your implementation where you passed activity object to
>   initialize drive api in rest.java. I am in a situation where i cant
>   send an activity object to this class.but i have an activity to gain
>   authorization.Is there any way to reinitialize these drive objects
>   without using activity object as i already got authorized once?

I have to admit i don't have time to analyze all the code in your question, so I'll try to focus on the [REST](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java) singleton class. As you see:

```
private static com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGOOSvc;
...
static void init(Activity ctx){
  mGOOSvc = new Drive.Builder(
    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), 
    new GsonFactory(),
    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
      ctx,                     // or ctx.getApplicationContext(),
      Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
    )
  ).build();
}
```

needs activity context for `GoogleAccountCredential` (will except Application context as well). This would be one-time-only initialization and you can use the static `mGOOSvc` as long as your app's alive.

**BUT**, the Activity context is also needed in case of `execute()` failure in order to resolve the `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`. This exception is resolved by means of `startActivityForResult((((UserRecoverableAuthIOException)ex).getIntent()),...)` with subsequent `onActivityResult()`. This error can happen anytime, since the authorization can be revoked from the outside (http://drive.google.com > Settings > Manage Apps > ... > Disconnect from Drive).

The conclusion is, if you decide to ignore the possibility of re-occurrence of the `UserRecoverableAuthIOException` (you ignore this exception or handle it yourself), **you may be able to get away with one-time-only call to** `init()`. Notice that this is exactly what the REST class does, it calls the `connect()` method once and ignores subsequent execute() errors. And remember, REST is a singleton and as long as the static `mGOOSvc` is alive, you can address it from Activities or Services.

There is another scenario when you have to call `init()` again. That is in case of account switch as seen in the REQ_ACCPICK trail [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/MainActivity.java). Your app would certainly need a new `mGOOSvc` for a new user (and again a new authorization if not authorized already).

So, you may be able to snatch the [REST class](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java), and just plug it into your code (non-ui thread calls). And you can drop the `.setSelectedAccountName(email)` as well if you don't handle multiple users.

Good Luck

Comment: Even if i handle that exception by restarting that authorisation activity i separately made.Still it should atleast work once by just using application context inside service.No?

Comment: I use that REST class from a SyncService only. 'init()' once on app start in resistant fragment, re-init again for a new user, and then just calling REST.foo()s. Service doesn't even need non-UI thread.

Comment: OK I got it. But my case is even more complex. The service and this class (and an auth activity) are in a separate package being communicated by aidl. So I will be able to run it first time when authorising using activity. But second time when I just directly initialise inside service it wont work as I can't send an activity object through aidl. So I still don't have a working solution.

Comment: Looks like they released v3 which specially contains "Authorization information is stored with the app, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization" .Though i am still having same problem with it